# How to change H2 color when BODY element's background color is toggled ON/OFF (CSS Class) by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the H2 color, when the background color of BODY is (in my case toggled sea blue when a button is clicked) toggled ON/OFF using a CSS Class (containing the required background color style)?

[image: CSS class defined in HTML doc]

I used the following conditional inside the callback function for my event listener, which is supposed to check if the button is clicked or not.

[image: Logic to check if the button is clicked and then check for the background color]

The problem here is though that I don't see the color of H2 change when the BODY background is `#42f4df`. My conditional only runs the else part of the code I'm assuming.
How can I fix this and make my H2 change color accordingly?
I've attached the images of the result I see too.

**Initially**
[image: 1. Initially]

**Click the button once**
[image: 2. Click the button once]

**Click the button once again**
[image: 3. Click the button again]

Comment: Can you add the code here (Not screenshots of code)?

Answer (score 2):

Just toggle class for parent element and style it accordingly

```js
function toggleclass() {
  var element = document.getElementById("parent");
  element.classList.toggle("newstyle");
}
```

```css
#parent { background: #eee; padding: 20px; }
#parent h1 { color: red; }

#parent.newstyle { background: green; }
#parent.newstyle h1 { color: white; }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <h1>My header</h1>
  <button onclick="toggleclass()">Click me</button>
</div>
```